# Does $ax \equiv b \pmod m$ have exactly one solution for groups in general?

Tags: group-theory

In the context of the chinese remainder theorem there is a lemma:

> **Lemma 1:** Let $a, b, m \in \mathbb Z$ with $m \geq 2$ and $\gcd(a,m)=1$.
>
> Then the equation $ax \equiv b \pmod m$ has exactly one solution
> in $\mathbb Z_m$.

I am trying to contrast that with the following statement about groups:

> **Lemma 2:**
>
> Let $G = (S, \circ)$ be a group, thus subject to the group axioms
>
> - **G1** $\circ$ is associative
> - **G2** There exists a neutral element $e \in S$
> - **G3** Every element $a \in S$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$
>
> From these axioms it can be derived that $\circ$ is surjective, i.e.
> that
>
> $$\exists x : a \circ x = b \text{ and } \exists y : y \circ a = b$$

Now what I am interested in is how to prove the second lemma.
My first thought was to use the proof of the first lemma as a guide, but that fails almost immediately:
The proof for the first lemma uses results from the euclidean algorithm, in particular that $\exists f, g: af + mg = \gcd(a, m) = 1$, which only works for euclidean rings but we only have a group.

My second observation is that Lemma 2 is a weaker statement than Lemma 1 since L2 only asserts existence, but not uniqueness of $x$ and $y$.

Long story short, I have three questions:

- How do I prove Lemma 2 with only the 3 group axioms?
- Is it really true that Lemma 2 is a weaker version of Lemma 1, or is there really no connection between those two lemmas.
- Is there a way to prove Lemma 1 for groups in general, or is it only possible for euclidean rings?

For reference, I got both lemmas from the book "Diskrete Strukturen Band 1", second edition by Steger.

Comment: Lemma $1$ says that $U(n)=(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ is indeed a group under multiplication, giving the existence of a unique inverse element. Lemma $2$ is only saying that **if** we have already a group, then ....

Comment: In a group, you also have uniqueness, because of the *cancellation rule*: if $ax=b=ax'$, then $ax=ax'\implies x=x'$, and similarly for the left multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

They are special cases of the following (in the commutative case).

**Lemma** $ $ TFAE for $\,a\in M\,$ a commutative monoid
$(1)\ \  \forall\ b\in M\!:\ ax=b\,$ has a unique root $\,x\in M$
$(2)\ \  \forall\ b\in M\!:\ ax=b\,$ has a root $\,x\in M$
$(3)\ \ a\,$ has an inverse $\,a^{-1}\in M$

**Proof** $\ (1\!\Rightarrow\! 2)\ $ Clear. $\ (2\!\Rightarrow\! 3)\ $ Let $\,b =  1.\ $ $\ (3\!\Rightarrow\! 1)\ \  ax = b\!\iff\! x = a^{-1}b\,$ by scaling by $\,a^{\pm 1}$.